# Evaluate the integral: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}(tx)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

I've been trying to evaluate the integral for a while now, and I've been unable to find it anywhere...
I tried substituting $\tan^{-1}(tx)$ as $u$ but got nowhere... I have done dozens of other substitutions...
I've been told to use the properties of gaussian integrals and the gamma function, but can't seem to figure out a way to bring in $\mathrm{e}$...
A few hints that point in the right direction to think will really help!

It would be really really helpful if you could solve this using only the properties of gaussian and gamma functions!

Comment: Call this integral $f(t)$. Evaluate $f^\prime (t)$ with partial fractions, then use $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand exactly what you are talking about...

Comment: How will the derivative of the function give me information about the function itself?

Comment: Maybe you can integrate the derivative of the function.

Comment: And, also, is there any possible way to do this with gaussian integrals or the gamma function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let:
$$
I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan tx}{x(1+x^2)}dx.
$$
Then
$$
I'(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x^2)}dx=
\frac1{t^2-1}\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{t^2}{1+t^2x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]dx\\
=\frac1{t^2-1} \left[t\arctan(tx)-\arctan x\right]_0^\infty=\frac\pi2\frac{|t|-1}{t^2-1}=\frac\pi2\frac1{|t|+1}.
$$
Finally integrating the last expression over $t$ one obtains:
$$
I(t)=I(0)+\frac\pi2\text {sgn}(t)\log(|t|+1)=\text {sgn}(t)\frac\pi2\log(|t|+1).
$$

Comment: Wouldn't $\left[t\tan^{-1}\left(tx\right)-\tan^{-1}x\right]^{ }$ from 0 to infinity be 0?

Comment: @PratikApshinge No. It will be $(t-1)\pi/2$.

Comment: I'm so sorry, made a calculation mistake!

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

We can write $\arctan(tx)=\int_0^t \frac{x}{1+y^2x^2}\,dy$.  Proceeding, we find that for $t>0$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(tx)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}\int_0^t \frac1{1+y^2x^2}\,dy\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{Fubini}}\int_0^t \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2x^2)}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^t \frac{\pi/2}{y+1}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 \log(1+t)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the integral of interest is an odd function of $t$, we have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(tx)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx=\begin{cases}\frac\pi 2\log(1+t)&, t>0\\\\0&,t=0\\\\-\frac\pi2 \log(1-t)&,t<0\end{cases}$$